# FileTransfer onprogress not working - PhoneGap 3.5.0

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

The `onprogress` event handler never seems to be called. The success callback comes through fine and the download works. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
filesystem.root.getFile('/path/to/file', { create: true }, function (file) {

    var transfer = new FileTransfer();

    transfer.onprogress = function () {
        console.log(arguments);
    };

    transfer.download(
        'http://example.com/path/to/file',
        file.toURL(),
        function () { console.log('success'); },
        function () { console.log('error'); },
        true
    );

}, function () { console.log('error'); });
```

The app uses PhoneGap 3.5.0 with the newest file and file-transfer plugins. I'm testing on an iPad with iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the *arguments* variable on the *onprogress* function definition.

It should be:

```
transfer.onprogress = function (progressEvent) {
    console.log(progressEvent);
    console.log(progressEvent.loaded); //Loaded bytes
    console.log(progressEvent.total); //Total bytes
    console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable); //TRUE if the destination server informs total file length
};
```

You can find the docs here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Hope it helps!

Comment: Onprogress function is not being triggered on my app. It's the same as the examples provided. Any ideas? Cordova 6.3.1 - File transfer 1.5.1

Comment: This appears to be a known bug in the Apache File Transfer plugin, see  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9936

Comment: @tonesforchris is there a solution for the bug? I followed your link but the discussion there didn't look like to get to any results.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying, unfortunately at this point I can't recall specifically what solved the problem, but I seem to recall different behavior between the emulator and on the device. Rebuilding the app eventually succeeded, but I couldn't say if there was other factors.